# How to simulate submit handler being not called when required input fields in form are empty?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I recently started testing with Jest and react-testing-library. But I ran into a little problem. I am testing my component which looks like this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Login = () => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState<string>('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState<string>('');

  const handleSubmit = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} data-testid="loginForm">
        <label>
          Username:
          <input
            required
            type="text"
            data-testid="usernameText"
            placeholder="e.g. JohnLukeThe3rd"
            value={username}
            onChange={(event) => setUsername(event.target.value)}
            autoFocus
          />
        </label>
        <label>
          Password:
          <input
            required
            type="password"
            data-testid="passwordText"
            placeholder="e.g. ••••••••••"
            value={password}
            onChange={(event) => setPassword(event.target.value)}
          />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" data-testid="loginButton" value="Login" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

As far as I understand onSubmit is not called when form is submitted but form's required input fields are empty. I checked this behavior by inserting a console.log('Hey') in handleSubmit but nothing got printed. So, I thought that in my test the same should happen. When I check if submit handler doesn't get called when input is empty it should succeed. But it doesn't. It fails.

Here's the testing code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  render,
  fireEvent,
  cleanup,
  RenderResult,
} from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
import Login from '../components/Login';

describe('<Login />', () => {
  let screen: RenderResult;
  beforeEach(() => {
    screen = render(<Login />);
  });
  afterEach(cleanup);

  describe('typing user info', () => {
    it('shows username and password', async () => {
      expect(screen.queryByDisplayValue('JohnLukeThe3rd')).toBeNull();
      await userEvent.type(
        screen.getByLabelText(/username/i),
        'JohnLukeThe3rd',
      );
      await userEvent.type(screen.getByLabelText(/password/i), 'Password123');
      expect(screen.queryByDisplayValue('JohnLukeThe3rd')).toBeInTheDocument();
      expect(screen.queryByDisplayValue('Password123')).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
  });

  describe('clicking login button', () => {
    let loginButton: HTMLElement;
    let submitHandler: jest.Mock;
    let form: HTMLElement;

    beforeEach(() => {
      loginButton = screen.getByText(/login/i);
      submitHandler = jest.fn((e) => e.preventDefault());
      form = screen.getByTestId(/loginForm/i);
      form.onsubmit = submitHandler;
    });


    // problem area here
    it('does not call submit handler if fields empty', () => {
      expect(submitHandler).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
      userEvent.click(loginButton);
      expect(submitHandler).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
    // problem area ends


    it('calls submit handler if fields non-empty', async () => {
      expect(submitHandler).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
      const usernameField = screen.getByTestId('usernameText');
      const passwordField = screen.getByTestId('passwordText');
      await userEvent.type(usernameField, 'JohnLukeThe3rd');
      await userEvent.type(passwordField, 'Password123');
      await userEvent.click(loginButton);
      expect(submitHandler).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
  });
});
```

The test 'does not call submit handler if fields empty' fails. What am I doing wrong? I couldn't find any information on testing form with required input fields anywhere. Am I doing it wrong? Thanks.

Also, just so you know: I did screen.debug() in the test and both input's value was 'value=""'

Comment: Preventing form submission when a `required` field is empty is client behavior; that's up to Chrome, Firefox, Mobile Chrome, Mobile Safari, etc. to implement. Jest knows only about your JavaScript and does not try to mimic native client behavior. Old versions of Chrome, Firefox, and IE, for example, did not yet implement validations: https://caniuse.com/#feat=form-validation

Comment: Thank you very much. That's a concise and clear answer I was looking for.

Comment: @RossAllen also, a followup would be. Is it a good idea, then, because it is not used in EVERY browser out there to still include empty input validation in my handleSubmit? To check if username and password state is not empty.